# How to read a TXT file and store only int in C

Tags: c++, c

So i have to do a code where i read a txt file on this format:

> {int}, {int}, {int}, {int}, {int}, {int} (next line)
>
> {int}, {int}, {int}, {int}, {int}, {int} (next line)

basically it will have an int, comma, space, 6 per line, immediately a \n(no space in last line component), and the number of lines is variable, it need to be able to read this file, and save only the numbers into the array. i plan on reading the file twice, one for set the size of the array, and the second to store values into it, since i do not need to store dynamically, but i do not know how to read this file since it has commas and spaces, also i dont know how to store those values. my idea is to do something like that: (will have errors, i am not too experient)

```
int main(){
 int i; //i is the controller for loop
 int l; //l is the number of lines
 FILE *A= 'file and read type';
 for(i=0; ???; i++){
 "I dont know how to implement a counter of lines and store into l variable"
 }
  int array[l][6]; //declaring the array with 6 spaces and number of lines as the number given in the first reading
  "Now it is the code to store in the array only the numbers, but how to do it ?"
}
```

hope it helps to understand what i need, thanks for the help.

Comment: In C, you can use `scanf()`. In C++, you can use `std::getline()` and `std::istringstream`. You don't need to read the file twice. In C, allocate a decent array size up front, and if you reach its capacity then just reallocate it as you go. In C++, use `std::vector` for the array, it will resize itself dynamically as needed.

Comment: you can do all in one loop, you do not need first to count the number of lines then to read again to save the values. Why `FILE *A= 'file and read type';`, you do not know how to open a file ? Your level of knowledge of C++/C++ seems too low and we cannot help you in an efficient way, you have to read book/tutorial about C and C++ to have the basis of the language

Comment: I do know how to open, i just dont have the txt, and since i did not effectively started the program yet i did not program it

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
FILE *F = fopen("fileName.txt", r);
fscanf(f, "%d %d %d %d %d %d\n", arr[l][0], arr[l][1], arr[l][2], arr[l][3], arr[l][4], arr[l][5]);
```

if you want to read characters instead of *digits* you can change `%d` to `%c`.